# Minimum amount using Dwolla payment button?

Tags: dwolla

One question on using the payment button and facilitator fee:

I set my facilitator fee at 2% and noticed then I was unable to charge less than $0.26 with the payment button.

Am I "doing it wrong"?

Also, is this documented anywhere? If not, could it be?

More importantly, I'd like to make the suggestion for a tiered facilitator fee such that users could pay each other less than $0.26 and the facilitator would NOT get the 2%.
But the payment button would still work for amounts less than $0.26 and the facilitator fee would only kick in if the amount was $0.26 or greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwolla's minimum transaction amount is $0.01. Since you set your facilitator fee to default to a 2% of the transaction amount, Dwolla must enforce a total amount that would cover both the transaction total amount, and the facilitator amount to be of at least $0.01 value. The minimum transaction amount that would satisfy that requirement for the facilitator fee is $0.25 ($0.25 x 2% = $0.01), add to that the minimum transaction amount of $0.01, and you got yourself $0.26.

Conclusion - either disable the facilitator fee feature in your application's features page, or simply override the facilitator fee amount to $0.00 in your API call.

Comment: -@Michael, is there any chance the minimum transaction amount when using the facilitator fee would be lowered from $.025 to something less? Regardless, this $0.25 "requirement" isn't in the documentation as far as I can tell.  Would be nice to add this sentence.